# add new environment variable [system] using power shell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am trying to add new Environment variable in my windows 10 system , i am using below powershell command to add System variable

> $env:ITH_PYTHON_PATH = 'C:\Python27\Python.exe'

i can see command is successful in adding the new values, and i can get back value when i use command $env:ITH_PYTHON_PATH.

1. I cannot see updated path when i manually go to the system property Environment variable
2. After reboot $env:ITH_PYTHON_PATH is also not seen.

Is there any better way to add environment variable permanently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ITH_PYTHON_PATH", "C:\Python27\Python.exe", "Machine")
```

Comment: please tell me about the last parameter "Machine". What it does?